# Creating Integration Tests for Magento 2 Modules

Tags: php, magento2, phpunit, integration-test

So far for my Magento 2 testing needs, I've been using PHP Unit as (more or less) an acceptance tester -- testing results of server and HTML requests made into a system with my module(s) installed.  I'd like to be able to create my own integration tests. Do the testing tools that ship with Magento 2 allow third party developers to create their own integration tests that leverage Magento's test framework code?  Or will we all be rolling our own bootstrap?

That is

1. I am a Magento developer
2. I'd like to create an integration test
3. I'd my integration test to have a fully bootstrap Magento environment to play in (i.e object manager and/or dependency injection to use)
4. I'd like my integration test to extend the  `Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController` test so I have the same helpers as Magento tests
5. I'd like to be able to run my tests **in isolation** from the rest of the test suite (i.e. not have to wait 2 hours to run my 15 seconds of tests)
6. I'd like my tests stored separately from Magento's tests

The dev docs site has some starter articles on testing, but they seem oriented at running the tests that ship with Magento and not creating and running your own tests.  There's [the old sample modules](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-newpage/Test/Unit/IndexTest.php), but they all extend the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class and seem to be **unit tests** (i.e. testing code that doesn't rely on the Magento framework)

Is there a Magento provided way of doing this?

If not, has anyone rolled their own setup in such a way that the test of the Magento developer community could adopt it as a standard?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works for us but we haven't yet looked into moving them to a separate location to address 6.)

1.) Place your integration tests under `dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Vendor`
2.) copy `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.dist.xml`
to
`dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml`

and replace

```
        <directory suffix="Test.php">testsuite</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../update/dev/tests/integration/testsuite</directory>
        <exclude>testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity</exclude>
        <exclude>testsuite/Magento/MemoryUsageTest.php</exclude>
```

with

```
        <directory suffix="Test.php">testsuite/Vendor</directory>
```

3.) run it `../../../vendor/bin/phpunit` or with `../../../vendor/bin/phpunit path/to/tests` from the dev/test/integration folder

Please note that the integration tests take longer than 15 seconds, at least on first run as it essentially installs Magento. You can save on subsequent runs if you use

`<const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="disabled"/>`

in your `phpunit.xml`

Answer (score 11):

I have played a little bit with the integration tests, and this is what I found so far.

Basically, I've followed similar steps to what Fooman said, with some differences in order to make the integration test be part of my module.

These are the steps I followed:

1- Place your integration tests under `app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Test/Integration`

2- Copy `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.dist.xml` to `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml`

and replace

```
<testsuite name="Magento Integration Tests">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">testsuite</directory>
    <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../update/dev/tests/integration/testsuite</directory>
    <exclude>testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity</exclude>
    <exclude>testsuite/Magento/MemoryUsageTest.php</exclude>
</testsuite>
```

with

```
<testsuite name="Magento Integration Tests">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Test/Integration</directory>
</testsuite>
```

3- Then I run it using the CLI tool `bin/magento dev:test:run integration`

You should have in mind what Fooman says about the "TESTS_CLEANUP" and the time it takes to setup the integration tests if you have the cleanup enable.

Here I add a functional example for further reference. You will see how you can access the object manager, and generate instance of Magento classes, as well as using Magento fixtures.

**app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Controller/Order/Info.php**

```
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Info
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Return Json OrderInfo
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $this
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $orderInfo = [
            'total' => $order->getBaseGrandTotal()
        ];

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        return $result->setData($orderInfo);
    }

}
```

---

**app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="vendor_custommodule" frontName="vendor_custommodule">
            <module name="Vendor_CustomModule"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

---

**app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CustomModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

---

**app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Test/Integration/Controller/Order/InfoTest.php**

```
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Controller\Order;

use Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController;

class InfoTest extends AbstractController
{
    public function getOrderInfoActionDataProvider()
    {
        return [
            'order with one simple item' => [
                'incrementId' => '100000001',
                'contentType' => 'application/json',
                'orderTotal' => 100
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider getOrderInfoActionDataProvider
     * @magentoDataFixture Magento/Sales/_files/order.php
     */
    public function testOrderInfoAction($incrementId, $expectedContentType, $expectedOrderTotal)
    {
        /** @var $objectManager \Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager */
        $objectManager = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager();

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory */
        $orderFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory');
        $order = $orderFactory->create();
        $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

        $this->dispatch("vendor_custommodule/order/info/id/{$order->getId()}");

        $contentType = $this->getResponse()->getHeader('Content-Type');
        $this->assertEquals($expectedContentType, $contentType->getFieldValue());

        $responseJson = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
        $responseArray = json_decode($responseJson, true);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedOrderTotal, $responseArray['total']);
    }
}
```

---

**app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CustomModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Please note that your own solution is fine and it works, as long as you're using the fixtures of the Magento core. If you want to use your own fixtures, you will bump into the issues as discussed earlier.

Answer (score 11):

I've successfully placed my integration tests into a separate directory: `src/My/Module/test/integration`. It could be any other directory as well, like `app/code/My/Module/Test`.

Add them as new test suite to the Magento integration tests: Copy `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist` to `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml` and add the following in the `<testsuites>` node:

```
<testsuite name="My_Module">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../src/My/Module/test</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Then run the tests like this from the `dev/tests/integration` directory:

```
../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "My_Module"
```

With the `--testsuite` parameter you can select one test suite by name, so that not all integration tests are run at once

### Update: Fixtures

To use own fixtures, a little workaround was necessary, because in `Magento\TestFramework\Annotation` the fixture base directory is defined globally. But fortunately Magento allows method names as fixtures as well, so the following works:

```
/**
 * @magentoDataFixture loadFixture
 */
public function testSomething()
{
}

public static function loadFixture()
{
    include __DIR__ . '/_files/something_fixture.php';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you run into problems when using the @magentoDataFixture here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Annotation/DataFixture.php#L171 especially when combining with a custom fixture from your module with a core one?

Comment: tbh I did not try it yet but it looks like a problem, yeah. Might be necessary to set the include path to make these fixtures work.

Comment: @KristofatFooman Found a solution for the fixtures, see update

Comment: Great solution. There might be a couple of flaws here. First of all, there is a typo - the `__DIR__` should be followed by a slash (`/_files`). Second, the fixture is loaded from within the TestFramework so that the `__DIR__` actually points to the TestFramework directory and not your own module. The `ComponentRegistrar` can be used for this: `require $ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ComponentRegistrar::class)->getPath('module', 'Foo_Bar').'/Test/Integration/_files/example.php';`

Comment: @JisseReitsma I just now saw your comment, thanks! 1. Fixed the typo! 2. No, __DIR__ is a magic constant that's resolved on compilation (not on runtime) to the directory of the current file, just like  __FILE__ is resolved to the full path of the file. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php