# How do Magento2 Integration and Functional Test relate to composer vendor folder?

Tags: magento2, composer, testing, integration-test, api-functional-tests

I want to write a full test suite for my new module. Unit tests are no problem as they can be tested in isolation, and therefore can be in a tests folder within the package.

However Integration and Functional tests act on the whole application, the Magento core has these at root level, so to my question.

So if we are to have the tests controlled by a composer package how do we get them into a root level folder?

I have found nothing in the documentation on what best practice is. Are third party module developers only writing Unit Tests?

I'm not aiming to distribute my module so I could put my Unit tests in the package and put Integration and Functional Tests at root level and source control them with the project. Is this the best plan - how are others doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've described it in another question for integration tests: [Creating Integration Tests for Magento 2 Modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93422/creating-integration-tests-for-magento-2-modules/104897#104897)

> I've successfully placed my integration tests into a separate
>   directory: `src/My/Module/test/integration`. It could be any other
>   directory as well, like `app/code/My/Module/Test`.
>
> Add them as new test suite to the Magento integration tests: Copy
>   `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist` to
>   `dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml` and add the following in the
>   `<testsuites>` node:
>
> ```
> <testsuite name="My_Module">
>     <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../src/My/Module/test</directory>
> </testsuite>
> ```
>
> Then run the tests like this from the `dev/tests/integration`
>   directory:
>
> ```
> ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite "My_Module"
> ```
>
> With the `--testsuite` parameter you can select one test suite by
>   name, so that not all integration tests are run at once

And for fixtures:

> To use own fixtures, a little workaround was necessary, because in
>   `Magento\TestFramework\Annotation` the fixture base directory is
>   defined globally. But fortunately Magento allows method names as
>   fixtures as well, so the following works:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @magentoDataFixture loadFixture
>  */
> public function testSomething()
> {
> }
>
> public static function loadFixture()
> {
>     include __DIR__ . '_files/something_fixture.php';
> }
> ```

You can use wild cards in the test suite definition, so for tests for any project specific modules in `app/code`, it can also look like this:

```
<directory suffix="Test.php">../../../app/code/*/*/Test</directory>
```

For functional tests it works in the same way.