# Can @magentoDataFixture files be inside the module itself and not on default directory dev/tests/integration/testsuite?

Tags: magento2, testing, phpunit, integration-test

A very good thing about Magento 2 is that we put together all files inside the module itself. Layout XML, Templates, Less/Sass, Blocks, Models, Helpers, API, SQL scripts and everything. It's important because when we enable, disable or even delete the module everything lays on a single directory.

However, when I add a `@magentoDataFixture` for an integration test, it says it should be placed on `dev/tests/integration/testsuite` directory, and not on the module itself. The more directories, the more difficult to maintain. It looks like M1 with `app` and `skin` directories where files became very far away from each other, in terms of tree directory.

Example:

```
/**
 * @magentoDataFixture MyNamespace/MyModule/_files/create_some_data_here.php
 */
class CustomIntegrationTestTest extends AbstractController
{
```

Magento will look up on the directory:
`dev/tests/integration/testsuite/MyNamespace/MyModule/_files/create_some_data_here.php`

and not somewhere like this:
`app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Test/....../_files/create_some_data_here.php`

Can `@magentoDataFixture` files be inside the module itself and not on default directory dev/tests/integration/testsuite?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93422/creating-integration-tests-for-magento-2-modules/104897#104897

Comment: (however you may want to take a look into https://github.com/tddwizard/magento2-fixtures for an object oriented fixture approach instead of procedural spaghetti scripts)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. You can pass a relative path starting from `dev/tests/integration/testsuite` and Magento will pickup the fixture.

If you have the fixture `app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Test/_files/create_some_data_here.php` you can use the following `@magentoDataFixture` annotation:

```php
/**
 * @magentoDataFixture ../../../../app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Test/_files/create_some_data_here.php
 */
public function testSomething() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if test class has multiple assertions then it would be great to use it as a method because annotations use a relative path.

```
/**
 * @magentoDataFixture loadInitialFixtures
 */
public function testSomething() {}

/**
 * @magentoDataFixture loadInitialFixtures
 */
public function testSomethingOther() {}

/**
 * @magentoDataFixture loadInitialFixtures
 */
public function testSomethingSomeOther() {}


/**
* Loads some data creation scripts because annotations use a relative path
*/
public static function loadInitialFixtures(){
    require __DIR__ . '/../../_files/create_some_data_here.php';
}

/**
* Rollback some data creation scripts because annotations use a relative path
*/
public static function loadInitialFixturesRollback() {
    require __DIR__ . '/../../_files/create_some_data_here_rollback.php';
}
```